# Grouping layers in Table of Contents in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, query-layer, group-layer

I'm trying to group layers in the table of content so that I can expand or collapse them as needed.  Not sure how.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Comment: Select (highlight) two or more layers, then right-click. The context menu has a Group option.

Comment: The documentation on [Working with group layers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/working-with-group-layers.htm) can be found using Google to search on 'ArcGIS group layer'.

Comment: This is a pretty low quality question.

Comment: @Adam Although this question is succinct, I believe it will benefit future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esri has a good help section on [Working with group layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/working-with-group-layers.htm). Here are two approaches:

1) Select all the layers you want to group in the table of contents > right click selected layers > Group

[image]

2) Add a new group layer by right-clicking on the layers in the table of contents. Then simply drag and drop or add layers into the group.
    Make sure to select the "List by Drawing Order" tab to see the group
    layers.

[image]